# DC to phase relationship with Low pass filtered sine and square wave multiplication and it's pitfalls. IQ Demodulation

Tags: demodulation

From what I have read about signal (de)modulation I understand that multiplying two sine waves, both with the same frequency, gives a two frequency component sine wave. One at DC and one at $2\omega$. Using a low pass filter will let us remove the $2\omega$ component. Now DC amplitude is proportional to the phase difference between the two sine waves.

So:
$$
A \sin(\omega t) \sin(\omega t + \theta) = \frac{A}{2}\cos(\theta) + \frac{A}{2}\cos(2\omega t + \theta) \rightarrow {\rm LPF} \rightarrow \frac{A}{2}\cos(\theta)
$$
where $\omega$ is the frequency, LPF is Low Pass Filter, $A$ is the amplitude and $\theta$ is the phase difference between the sine waves.

I made a Matlab program to plot this, then I tried with a square wave multiplied with a sine wave. I can see that there is still a connection between DC and phase by doing a FFT as well as in the time domain. I would like to see the math for the relationship between DC and phase.

For sine $\times$ sine, I have read that sampling with a frequency four times the modulated signal frequency will make it possible to get the I and Q values by subtracting samples in the following order:

$$
I(t) = s(t) - s(t-2)
$$
$$
Q(t) = s(t-3) - s(t-1)
$$
where
$$
s(t) = A\sin(\omega t + \theta)
$$

This I do not quite understand yet and therefore leads me to be unable to determine if this also is valid for a square $\times$ sine. Can anyone try to explain this to me?

I will appreciate any feedback on how to effectively do IQ demodulation on a micro-controller using a square reference waveform.

**Additional information:**

I wish to use a micro-controller to sample the analog sine and square (reference) signal and do IQ demodulation. I almost only find information about sine $\times$ sine and therefore want to know if there are any pitfalls using a reference square wave that I am not seeing yet.

Answer (score 2):

So if your sampling rate is four times the modulated signal frequency (and sampling synchronously) then $\omega= \pi/2$. So then
$$
\begin{array}
 II(t) &=& s(t) - s(t-2)\\
&=& A\sin(\pi/2 t + \theta) - A\sin(\pi/2 (t - 2) + \theta)\\
&=& 2A\sin(\pi/2 t + \theta) 
\end{array}
$$
and
$$
\begin{array}
 QQ(t) &=& s(t-3) - s(t-1)\\
&=& A\sin(\pi/2 (t-3) + \theta) - A\sin(\pi/2 (t - 1) + \theta)\\
&=& A\sin(\pi/2 t + \theta - 3\pi/2) - A\sin(\pi/2 t + \theta - \pi/2)\\
&=& 2A \cos((\pi/2 t + \theta - 3\pi/2 + \pi/2 t + \theta - \pi/2)/2) \\
&&\sin((\pi/2 t + \theta - 3\pi/2 - (\pi/2 t + \theta - \pi/2))/2)\\
&=& 2A\cos(\pi/2 t + \theta) 
\end{array}
$$

The trick will be to think about the square wave case, and see what this derivation tells you about that.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking?  Does "I = 2" mean $I(t-2)$ ?

Comment: I deleted the above comment as I was wrong (and it might be misleading). The algorithm above will not work with a square reference as the sine x square product wave does NOT phase shift the same way as the sine x sine product wave does when reference phase is adjusted. Only way to find I and Q when using square reference as far as I can see is to use a low pass filter and measure the outputs.

Comment: @PeterK. It's always good to see a problem worked out explicitly. This is not a "ping" yet, but definitely making progress on IQ - thanks!